# Bloch–Kato–Selmer group of a one-dimensional representation

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations, galois-cohomology

Let $L/\mathbb{Q}$ be a finite extension and let $V$ be a one-dimensional $L$-linear representation of $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$ which is given by $\chi\rho^*\kappa^n_{\text{cyc}}:G_{\mathbb{Q}}\rightarrow L^\times$, where $\rho$ is a Dirichlet character mod $p$, $\chi$ is a Dirichlet character mod $d$ for some $d$ prime to $p$ (both viewed as galois characters) and $\kappa_{\text{cyc}}$ is the cyclotomic character for the prime $p$. In particular the restriction of $V$ to $G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ is de Rham. Further we assume $n\leq0$ and $\chi\rho^*(-1)\cdot(-1)^n=-1$. To be precise, this representation comes from the Artin motive corresponding to $\chi$ twisted by $\rho^*$ and the Tate motive $\mathbb{Q}(n)$.

Let $S=\{\text{primes dividing $d$},p,\infty\}$ as a subset of the places of $\mathbb{Q}$. I want to show (if true) that
the Bloch–Kato–Selmer group
$$
H^1_f(\mathbb{Q},V)=\ker\left(H^1(G_{\mathbb{Q},S},V)\longrightarrow\bigoplus_{v\in S}\frac{H^1(\mathbb{Q}_v,V)}{H_\text f^1(\mathbb{Q}_v,V)}\right),
$$
is zero. Here the $H_\text f^1(\mathbb{Q}_v,V)$ are "local conditions", namely
$$
H_\text f^1(\mathbb{Q}_v,V)=\begin{cases}\ker(H^1(\mathbb{Q}_l,V)\overset{\operatorname{res}}{\longrightarrow}H^1(I_l,V)),& v=l\neq p\\
\ker(H^1(\mathbb{Q}_p,V)\longrightarrow H^1(\mathbb{Q}_p,B_{\text{cris}}\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}_p},V)),&v=p\\
H^1(\mathbb{R},V),&v=\infty,
\end{cases}
$$
where $I_l\subseteq G_{\mathbb{Q}_l}$ is the inertia subgroup.
One can show relatively easily that in this case one has $H^1_\text f(\mathbb{Q}_v,V)=0$ for all $v\in S$ and therefore it reduces to the question of whether the usual localization map
$$
H^1(G_{\mathbb{Q},S},V)\longrightarrow\bigoplus_{v\in S} H^1(\mathbb{Q}_v,V)
$$
is injective. To go further, I assume one has to use that $H^1(G,V)=\projlim_{n\in\mathbb{N}}H^1(G,T/p^nT)\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_L}L$, where $T\subseteq V$ is a $G$-stable $\mathcal{O}_L$-lattice and $G\in\{G_{\mathbb{Q},S},G_{\mathbb{Q}_v}\}$, and then use Pitou–Tate duality. In [Neukirch, Schmidt, and Wingberg - Cohomology of number fields](https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Eschmidt/NSW2e/NSW2.3.pdf), §9.1 they discuss some cases where the localization map is zero, but it is mainly about finite simple $G$-modules and I don't see how I can apply this here. One can also show that $H_\text f^1(\mathbb{Q},V)=0$ if and only if
$$
H_\text f^1(\mathbb{Q},V/T)=\ker\left(H^1(G_{\mathbb{Q},S},V/T)\longrightarrow\bigoplus_{v\in S}\frac{H^1(\mathbb{Q}_v,V/T)}{H_\text f^1(\mathbb{Q}_v,V/T)}\right)
$$
is finite. But I don't know how to prove this either. It would be great if someone could help.